# I am trying to pass a variable from php into a sql function for a LIMIT value

Tags: php, sql, limit

I am attempting to add multiple pages to display data on my website, rather than one long list. I am doing this by using LIMIT from sql. How can I pass my variable from php into the sql statement? Below is my code

$sql = 'SELECT fldDateLogged, fldUserEarnings ';

$sql .= 'FROM tblDataTracked ';

$sql .= 'WHERE fldEmail = ? ';

$sql .= 'LIMIT VariableHere, 5 ';

Is it a possibility that this can work? if so how can I pass my php variable into the VariableHere spot? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to bind it, just like for your `fldEmail`? If yes, what happened? What database vendor are you using? Mysql, Mssql, Postgres, Sqlite, Something else? What database driver are you using in PHP? Also post more context. How are you binding the values, preparing and executing the statement?

Comment: There are many examples here on SO, try searching for `php pagination`.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible. you can use quote or even bracket to do that.
for example `SELECT * from tmp_subtitle where token='{$token}'` or `SELECT * from tmp_subtitle where token="'".$token."'"`